# Why does a force downgrade causes an assembly load exception in .Net Core?

Tags: .net-core, nuget, assembly-loading

I have a sample solution with a console and library project. Both reference the same nuget but a different version. The console project also has a reference to the library project. So the structure is like this:

```
- Solution
    - ConsoleApp
        - Project Reference: Library
        - Nuget: NServiceBus.RabbitMQ (5.2.0)
    - Library
        - Nuget: NServiceBus.RabbitMQ (6.0.0)
```

You can find the solution [here](https://github.com/leendertdommicent/dependency-example).

Since Nuget uses the nearest wins rule, the nuget package that gets resolved is version 5.2.0. This is what I want, so far so good. But when I run the application and run a method of the Library I get the following exception:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'NServiceBus.Transport.RabbitMQ, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9fc386479f8a226c'. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (0x80131040)
```

In .NET Framework I would solve this with an assembly redirect. But that isn't available in .Net Core. I always thought that .Net Core solves this automatically by using the deps.json file. There I see the following statement:

```json
"Library/1.0.0": {
    "dependencies": {
        "NServiceBus.RabbitMQ": "5.2.0"
    },
    "runtime": {
        "Library.dll": {}
    }
}
```

But still at runtime he tries to resolve the 6.0.0 version. I'm using the latest .Dot Net 3.1.X SDK.

I'm I doing something wrong or does this seem like a bug?

For the record, this is a simple sample project. The actual situation where I need this is much more complex. I also do understand that doing this can cause runtime exceptions while running the application.

Comment: Are you sure, that different major number is not the main issue? I would try to avoid mixing major versions of the same nuget. New major number usually says "we have breaking changes here".

Comment: In terms of best practices you are absolutely right. But sometimes you know you are not calling any code that has a breaking change. And if you depend on some external libraries that do not have matching dependencies, this trick can be handy in some cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to be by design.

A little bit of searching, I found this: https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/issues/3408#issuecomment-319466999

> The coreclr will load an assembly of the version or higher than the reference. If the assembly discovered is lower than the reference then it fails.

Also this: https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/384#issuecomment-260457776

> downgrading the assembly version isn't supported on .NET Core

So, to confirm, I spent much more time than I intended looking/searching through https://github.com/dotnet/runtime. Eventually I found the assembly version compatibility method: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/172059af6623d04fa0468ec286ab2c240409abe3/src/coreclr/binder/assemblybindercommon.cpp#L49-L53

It checks all the components of the version separately, but if we look at just one, we can see what it's doing:

```cpp
            if (!pFoundVersion->HasMajor() || pRequestedVersion->GetMajor() > pFoundVersion->GetMajor())
            {
                // - A specific requested version component does not match an unspecified value for the same component in
                //   the found version, regardless of lesser-order version components
                // - Or, the requested version is greater than the found version
                return false;
            }
```

As the comment says, the loader will reject the assembly if the assembly's version is lower than the requested version. In your case, assuming that the assembly version matches the package version (which it doesn't have to), your library is requesting version 6.0.0, but the assembly loader/binder, found version 5.2.0 on disk, which is lower. Hence, it rejects that dll, keeps looking, but then can't find a suitable version of the assembly on the probing path and eventually throws the FileLoadException.

What's not clear to me is if this assembly compatibility is checked only on the default assembly loader, or even if you add your own event handler to [AssemblyLoadContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.loader.assemblyloadcontext?view=net-5.0).[Default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.loader.assemblyloadcontext.default?view=net-5.0).[Resolving](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.loader.assemblyloadcontext.resolving?view=net-5.0). You could try adding your own handler and when it requests the assembly of the higher version, you return the lower version assembly anyway.  It might be a way to work around the issue.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! I could not find anything on google about it. Guess I should start to search more on GitHub. For us it is a pity that it isn't supported anymore in .Net Core. It is something we have to take into account while developing our framework libraries. If we increase a dependency version, it means that everybody that uses the framework has to follow. And if semver versioning is strictly followed this is a good thing, but lot of libraries out there that do not contain breaking changes over major versions. So in those cases it is less flexible.